# Outputting text as a half diamond

Tags: java, string, substring, joptionpane

Assignment is to input text and then it prints out in the terminal as half a diamond. example:

```
T
 TE
  TEX
   TEXT
  TEX
 TE
T
```

I'm really close its just the last part. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

// The "number 4" class.
public class number4
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {            
        String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter a word:");
        int len = word.length ();
        String SPACES = "                              ";       
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
        {           
            System.out.print (word.substring (0,i) + System.lineSeparator());
            System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0,i));            
        }    
        String SPACES2 = "      ";          
        for (int g = len ; g>=0; g--)
        {           
            System.out.print (word.substring (0,g) + System.lineSeparator());  
            System.out.print(SPACES2.substring(g,g+1));              
        }        
        System.out.println();
    } // main method
} //number 4
```

The problem is at:   `System.out.print(SPACES.substring(g,g+1));` (the last part of the half diamond)

It currently looks like this:

```
T
 TE
  TEX
   TEXT
  TEX
  TE
  T
```

Comment: I just edited it thats what it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Here is new code:
I just had to put the Spaces.substring before the word.substring in the for loops

```
import javax.swing.*;

// The "number 4" class.
public class number4
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {            
        String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter a word:");
        int len = word.length ();
        String SPACES = "                              ";       
        for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
        { 
            System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0,i));            
            System.out.print (word.substring (0,i) + System.lineSeparator());           
        }            
        for (int g = len ; g>=0; g--)
        {          
            System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0,g));           
            System.out.print (word.substring (0,g) + System.lineSeparator());              
        }        
        System.out.println();
    } // main method
} //number 4
```

Answer (score 2):

The same would work in Java. Assuming `x = 'TEXT'`, `len(x) = 4`. We will go through the indices [0, 1, ..., 6]. This is the same as if you wrote `for(int i = 0; i<2*len; i++)`. If the current index is less than the length of the text we will increase the spacing, if it is greater we will decrease the spacing.

```
for i in range(2*len(x)-1):
    if i < len(x): 
        y = ' '*i + x[0:i+1]
    else: 
        y = ' '*(2*len(x)-i-2) + x[0:len(x)-i-1]
    print(y)
```

> T 
>    TE 
>      TEX 
>        TEXT 
>      TEX 
>    TE 
>  T

Comment: Can you modify my code and fix the error rather than create a whole new program. I have to use mine sorry